# How to avoid a nested query?

Tags: scala, graphql, slick, sangria

In Sangria I'm getting a list of users by IDs

```
lazy val UsersType: ObjectType[GraphQLContext, Seq[User]] = ObjectType("users", () =>
fields[GraphQLContext, Seq[User]](
    Field("users", ListType(UserDetailType), resolve = 
    _.value),
))
```

The Query works, but I have to write the name of the Query and the name of the Field "users" twice, they are the same.

The Query now is:

```
users(id: 123) {
    users {
        id
        name
    }
}
```

How to avoid the need to type the query name and the field name? How to turn the query to:

```
users(id: 123) {
    id
    name
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use ListType(UsersType) in schema

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).